# Interval running as a counter not being reset on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am in the middle of building a Pomodoro Timer, the counter should start at 25 minutes decrementing until 0, then run a 5-minute decrementing timer. Following the timer and break state should be reset ready to run again, so far so good.

However, I am having an issue with resetting the time whilst it is running on a button click. I have a function `resetTimer` which is currently being used to reinitialise the timer and break count at the end of each cycle, but if clicked whilst either timer or break is running (counting down to 0), then `resetTimer` does indeed run for a second but then the timer carries on as it did before the button firing the event.

I have tried calling `resetTimer` and `return` if a condition `resetClicked === true` which calls the function and it runs briefly but then carries on with the original timer.

I've also tried setting an initialising function which checks if `resetClicked === true` before calling the `start()` function and then calling this again in `resetTimer` but didn't work either.

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [sessionLength, setSessionLength] = useState(25);
  const [breakLength, setBreakLength] = useState(5);
  const [timerRunning, setTimerState] = useState(false);
  const [breakRunning, setBreakState] = useState(false);

  let countdown;
  let minutesToSecondsSession = sessionLength * 60;
  let minutestoSecondsBreak = breakLength * 60;
  const clear = () => clearInterval(countdown);

  const start = () => {
    if (timerRunning === false) {
      setTimerState(true);
      console.log("timer started");
      const now = Date.now();
      const then = now + minutesToSecondsSession * 1000;

      displayTimeLeftSession(minutesToSecondsSession);

      countdown = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
          clear(countdown);
          console.log("timer interval cleared");
          breakTimer();
        }

        displayTimeLeftSession(secondsLeft);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
  // end of timer function
  //
  // start of break timer
  function breakTimer() {
    if (breakRunning === false) {
      setBreakState(true);
      console.log("break timer started");
      const now = Date.now();
      const then = now + minutestoSecondsBreak * 1000;

      displayTimeLeftBreak(minutestoSecondsBreak);

      countdown = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
          console.log("break interval cleared");
          resetTimer();
          return;
        }

        displayTimeLeftBreak(secondsLeft);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  function displayTimeLeftSession(minutesToSecondsSession) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(minutesToSecondsSession / 60);
    const remainderSeconds = minutesToSecondsSession % 60;

    setSessionLength(`${minutes}:${remainderSeconds}`);
  }

  function displayTimeLeftBreak(minutesToSecondsBreak) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(minutesToSecondsBreak / 60);
    const remainderSeconds = minutesToSecondsBreak % 60;

    setBreakLength(`${minutes}:${remainderSeconds}`);
  }

  // end of display timer logic

  function incrementSession() {
    if (sessionLength <= 60) {
      setSessionLength(prev => prev + 1);
    }
  }

  function decrementSession() {
    if (sessionLength > 1) {
      setSessionLength(prev => prev - 1);
    }
  }

  function incrementBreak() {
    if (breakLength < 60) {
      setBreakLength(prev => prev + 1);
    }
  }

  function decrementBreak() {
    if (breakLength > 1) {
      setBreakLength(prev => prev - 1);
    }
  }

  const resetTimer = () => {
    clear(countdown);
    setTimerState(false);
    setBreakState(false);
    setSessionLength(0.05);
    setBreakLength(0.05);
    console.log("reset");
  };
```

Code is up until return(), have omitted the JSX to save space, just renders the timer onto the page anyway, had issues adding an embed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fcc-pomodoro-clock-3rxfh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**Edit:**
Tried defining each countdown as a separate globally scoped variable and then invoke clearInterval for each when required but the same problem persists.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [breakLength, setBreakLength] = useState(0.05);
  const [sessionLength, setSessionLength] = useState(20);
  const [timerRunning, setTimerState] = useState(false);
  const [breakRunning, setBreakState] = useState(false);

  let sessionCountdown;
  let breakCountdown;
  let minutesToSecondsSession = sessionLength * 60;
  let minutestoSecondsBreak = breakLength * 60;
  //const clear = () => clearInterval(countdown);

  const start = () => {
    if (timerRunning === false) {
      setTimerState(true);
      console.log("timer started");
      const now = Date.now();
      const then = now + minutesToSecondsSession * 1000;

      displayTimeLeftSession(minutesToSecondsSession);

      sessionCountdown = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
          clearInterval(sessionCountdown);
          console.log("timer interval cleared");
          breakTimer();
        }

        displayTimeLeftSession(secondsLeft);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
  // end of timer function
  //
  // start of break timer
  function breakTimer() {
    if (breakRunning === false) {
      setBreakState(true);
      console.log("break timer started");
      const now = Date.now();
      const then = now + minutestoSecondsBreak * 1000;

      displayTimeLeftBreak(minutestoSecondsBreak);

      breakCountdown = setInterval(() => {
        const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
          console.log("break interval cleared");
          clearInterval(breakCountdown);
          resetTimer();
          return;
        }

        displayTimeLeftBreak(secondsLeft);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }

  function displayTimeLeftSession(minutesToSecondsSession) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(minutesToSecondsSession / 60);
    const remainderSeconds = minutesToSecondsSession % 60;

    setSessionLength(`${minutes}:${remainderSeconds}`);
  }

  function displayTimeLeftBreak(minutesToSecondsBreak) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(minutesToSecondsBreak / 60);
    const remainderSeconds = minutesToSecondsBreak % 60;

    setBreakLength(`${minutes}:${remainderSeconds}`);
  }

  // end of display timer logic

  function incrementSession() {
    if (sessionLength <= 60) {
      setSessionLength(prev => prev + 1);
    }
  }

  function decrementSession() {
    if (sessionLength > 1) {
      setSessionLength(prev => prev - 1);
    }
  }

  function incrementBreak() {
    if (breakLength < 60) {
      setBreakLength(prev => prev + 1);
    }
  }

  function decrementBreak() {
    if (breakLength > 1) {
      setBreakLength(prev => prev - 1);
    }
  }

  const resetTimer = () => {
    clearInterval(sessionCountdown);
    clearInterval(breakCountdown);
    setTimerState(false);
    setBreakState(false);
    setSessionLength(0.05);
    setBreakLength(0.05);
    console.log("reset");
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Use can see a working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fcc-pomodoro-clock-zbvi9)

**Details:**

Every time `render` is executed new closures for `resetTimer()` and other functions are created. If you'll put `console.log(countdown)` right before `resetTimer()` declaration you will see that `countdown` is **always** `undefined`.

1. I really doubt that creating new functions on every render is a good idea.
2. But to fix this particular issue you can save result of `setInterval` to the state to use it later in `resetTimer()`

   ```js
   const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState(undefined);
   ```

   but inside `setInterval` you can still use closures, that's easier

   ```js
   const interval = setInterval(() => {
     ...
     if (secondsLeft === 0) {
       clearInterval(interval);
       ...
     }
     ...
   }, 1000);
   setCountdown(interval) // save it to the state
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Hi   your problem was with the variable used to store the intervals

you should put it outside the class

`let countdown;
export default function App() {.....
.....`

see code here  Reset button works

https://codesandbox.io/s/fcc-pomodoro-clock-7gt7f

Comment: Global variables are evil. Most of the time. In `React` components 99.99...% of times